# AWS Amplify Fullstack CI/CD breaks API (cors issues)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I have an Amplify app that is using the [AWS REST Express lambda function API](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/js). It is connected to the CI/CD so whenever I push to my branch (accept PR's) the app's frontend and backend services are built and deployed.

At this point, whenever I accept PR's / push code, the apps API will stop working. I then have to get on my local code, modify the API's app.js file and do a dummy push. Same code that I just pushed (minus the useless comment) and then the app on both my local machine and the deployed URL starts working again. The frontend build/deploy works fine - it's just the backend build/deploy that causes the API to only return CORS errors.

My question is how to fix my CI/CD so that I don't need to do the extra deployment locally.

Some extra notes - This is a React app with multiple environments deploying on different AWS accounts.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to help. What errors are you getting returned exactly? I've noticed that failing requests (e.g., 500 status codes) often show as CORS errors as well in the frontend, cause the headers aren't set properly when the code errors. What is the logging of the backend when the errors happen? Have you checked if there is a difference between the deployment packages that get created using the two different flows?

Comment: I can't see the logs on the Cloudformation side when I deploy via CI/CD. It's as if the hosted app isn't even making a request to API, all I get is CORS issues. I know the requests aren't failing because the same ones as soon as I deploy arbitrarily start working. What do you mean deployment packages? How can I test this :)

Comment: Now I'm just more confused ;). You've stated in your question that after deployment using a PR, your backend API stops working. That API must have some logs in Cloudwatch I presume? But now you're talking about Cloudformation, so is it the cloudformation that fails to deploy and corrupts your app in one way or another?

Comment: Oops my bad! I meant Cloudwatch. When I deploy via CI/CD (through PR) yes, my backend completely stops working. Even worse, after I've deployed, I don't see any logs in cloudwatch. It's as if the calls are not even making it to my API. 
My fix to this is to add a dummy comment to the backend app.js, and deploy from my local machine. Then poof - the hosted app is working again. Do you have any idea what that would be the case? Is there anyway to get more insight into the difference in deployment package of "amplify push" and CI/CD deployment?

Comment: In that case, I assume something will be wrong with your CI/CD. Can you share the details (CloudFormation f.e.) of the CI/CD setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a difference in the API stack being deployed for CLI push and CI/CD deployment.

The solution was to set my CI/CD Build Image to have the same Amplify CLI as my local version.

To do so:

1. Run `amplify --version` locally to get the version to copy onto Amplify Console
2. Copy the value in Amplify Console > Build Settings > Build Image Settings > Amplify CLI

[image: Where to Insert the local Amplify version]